# Is the damage done to the Golden Bean cumulative?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

I keep seeing the Golden Bean in Dreamy areas, and I don't get to damage him much before he runs.

Does his damage counter reset every time I see him, or are all these small battles breaking down his HP?

Answer (score 2):

Each Golden Beanie is a different enemy: the same way any other two enemies are different. Damaging one will not affect another.

Some tips for beating:

- His first chance after starting the battle or after getting off his back will always be an attack, and if you successfully counter the attack it will flip him on his back, where you can deal as much damage as you can. It will also guarantee that the bean will not run away next turn - so successful counters are all that is needed to beat him at any level.
- As you level up, the Golden Beanies do not become more powerful, so they become easier to beat as you progress through the game.